# Typorm migration needs permission to all tables in database

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestjs app and migrations configured to run automatically on startup. Recently, a new table was added to the database for aws dms. This table should not be included in migrations or accessed by the app in any way but needs to be in the same database for dms purposes. We did not give the user used by the app permissions to this new table and the migrations failed to run with the following error:

`Migration "migrations1673309585875" failed, error: permission denied for table awsdms_ddl_audit`

in the nestjs logs

```
ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Message: permission denied for sequence awsdms_ddl_audit_c_key_seq. Retrying (9)...
QueryFailedError: permission denied for sequence awsdms_ddl_audit_c_key_seq
at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:211:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Migration "migrations1673309585875" failed, error: permission denied for sequence awsdms_ddl_audit_c_key_seq
```

I want to reiterate that this migration does not include any changes to that table. It includes very minor changes to another table with no relation to the aws dms table.

The only thing I was able to find on this was this GitHub issue where someone had exactly the same problem and their solution was to grant permissions for the table and a sequence to that user. You can find that [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2215).

This solution worked for me but I would prefer to not have the permissions granted if I can avoid it. Is there a way to specify a table to be excluded in typeorm migration? There isn't anything in the migration related to that table and there never should be. I don't know what typeorm is doing to need permissions on this table.

Here's what I did to 'fix' the issue:

```sql
GRANT ALL
ON awsdms_ddl_audit
TO user_role;

GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE awsdms_ddl_audit_c_key_seq TO user_role;
```

Here's an example of our typeorm configuration

```js
// typeorm/config.ts
export const databaseConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host,
  port,
  username,
  password,
  database,
  entities,
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/**/*.js'],
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: true,
};
```

```js
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { databaseConfig } from './typeorm/config';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(databaseConfig)],
  controllers: [controllers],
  providers: [providers],
})
export class AppModule {}
```